# after installation 12.04 LTS (04) - is not encrypted?

Tags: encryption

Am testing here 12.04.04 LTS for amd64-mac and after installation - intended with encryption of /home - the installation is not encrypted ?! with which command can I find out, if the partition is encrypted ?!

Comment: Is non-encryption a so-called "penalty" for so-called "thieves" ?!

Comment: I remember that this was already an issue in 01 or 02 ?